# Micro Frontends: Is it possible to use Python for a micro fronted architecture based on webpack?

Tags: webpack, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I have been trying to dive into Micro Frontends recently. But i am getting stuck into which Micro Frontend Frameworks are most suitable for building application that use completely different codebases for its sub-apps. I am looking into Webpack Module Federation framework and want to know if it even supports python frameworks. And if so it would be really helpful to get some documentations if available.

Comment: Hi @Erbaz, did you get some information on this topic ? I am looking for the same things. And at this moment I found only information with nodejs +  a javascript frameworks.